# Tick-Tack-Toe Im making a ticktacktoe game and ive made the ui but i cant find a way to match every array of gameboard to the griditems

Tags: javascript

Tick-Tack-Toe Im making a ticktacktoe game and ive made the ui but i cant find a way to match every array of gameboard to the griditems.

So i need to find a way to match the gameboard array with my grid boxes. and then i could implement an algorithm to check the winner and append it on the screen on some sort of element. On the last code block you can see ive put it out. this is because it messed with my grid fuctionality.That is the codeblock that i want to do matching in and so forth.

```
HTMl 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="title"><h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="board"></div>
          <button class="Reset">Reset Game</button>
          <div class="winning-message"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
    

   
</body>
</html>
```

```
js
const Player = (name, symbol) => {
return{name, symbol}
}

const player1 = Player("Player X", "X")
const player2 = Player("Player O", "O")

const gameBoardObject = (() => {
    let gameBoard = ["", "","", "","", "","", "",""]
   return {gameBoard}
})();

const container = document.querySelector(".board");
function makeRows(rows, cols) {
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  
  
    for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
      let cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.id = c 
      let symbol = document.createElement("p")
      //cell.addEventListener("mouseover", colorSquare)
      cell.style.border = "2px solid black"
      container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
      cell.appendChild(symbol).className = "symbol"
      cell.addEventListener('click',handleClick, { once: true})
      
    }

    
};
makeRows(3, 3);
let circleTurn

function handleClick(e) {
    console.log(this.id)
    //placeMark
    const cell = e.target
    const currentPlayer =  circleTurn ? player1.symbol : player2.symbol
    placeMark(cell, currentPlayer)
    //Check For Win
    //Check for Draw
    //Switch Turns
    switchTurns()
    insertBoxes()
}

function switchTurns(){
    circleTurn = !circleTurn
}

function placeMark(cell, currentPlayer){
    cell.textContent = currentPlayer
   
}


/*let insertBoxes = (function() {
    const gridboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item")
    gridboxes[0].textContent = gameBoardObject.gameBoard
    gameBoardObject.gameBoard(push(gridboxes))
    console.log(gameBoardObject.gameBoard)
    return{}

})*/
```

```
css
:root {
    --grid-cols: 1;
    --grid-rows: 1;
    --mark-size: calc(var(--cell-size) * .9);
}

.flex-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(96, 79, 252, 0.082), white);
}

.board {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 0 2px rgb(255, 255, 255),
      0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).